# How can I get the data from Plain Old Java Objects to Oracle BI Publisher?

Tags: java, oracle, reporting-services, dao, pojo

I have a customer who uses Oracle BI Publisher.  Today we have to write stored procedures and execute those from BI Publisher to get the data out. Similar to that we have to use DAOs to execute stored procs and get the data out.  I wonder if it would be possible to integrate BI Publisher with DAOs that would get the data DIRECTLY from database in simple SQL statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My client wrote JDBC driver, so BI Publisher thinks it gets the data from DBMS, instead we got the data from POJOs.